# Kubernetes Dashboard hangs

Tags: kubernetes

I've followed the instructions on the kubernetes website to use the ui (dashboard) and it isn't running.  I've also downloaded and altered the yaml file for the following in the service:

nodePort: 31313

```
core@kube-master ~ $ kubectl create -f kubernetes-dashboard.yaml 
deployment "kubernetes-dashboard" created
You have exposed your service on an external port on all nodes in your
cluster.  If you want to expose this service to the external internet, you may
need to set up firewall rules for the service port(s) (tcp:31313) to serve traffic.
```

This all looks good but the endpoint doesn't exist and I see no services:

```
core@kube-master ~ $ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at http://104.236.15.140:8080
core@kube-master ~ $ kubectl get ep kubernetes-dashboard
Error from server: endpoints "kubernetes-dashboard" not found
```

When I go to the master url at port 31313, nothing, but when I try one of the minions on that port it hangs.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong and I've searched for this issue but it seems that every one else's problems are slightly different.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> This all looks good but the endpoint doesn't exist and I see no services

This is in the `kube-system` namespace, unless you created the dashboard, pods, rc etc in another namespace through your custom yaml.

> When I go to the master url at port 31313, nothing,

this isn't supposed to work

> but when I try one of the minions on that port it hangs.

this should work if you have endpoints and the minion is running kube-proxy, unless you have a firewall rule in place.

Suggest debugging a simple nodePort service first, if that works, you'd have figure out enough to troubleshoot this, I guess. Maybe the one described here: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/connecting-applications/#exposing-the-service

This is also a good resources for debugging service connectivity: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/debugging-services/